# TypeScript: "keyof this" in constructor signature

Tags: javascript, typescript

It is possible to use `keyof this` in the signature of a class method but not in the constructor (error: A 'this' type is available only in a non-static member of a class or interface.). I'd like to extend the class and the type checking be intact in sub classes.
Why the error and how can i work around it?
The code:

```js
class Foo {

  constructor(k: keyof this/*Error 2526 here*/) {}

  method(k: keyof this) {}
}

class Bar extends Foo{
  constructor() {
    super("prop");
  }
  prop = 12;
}

new Bar().method("prop");
```

code and error in typescript playgorund:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?ts=3.8.3&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=26#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQrrWPAdhALgE4Cuw+8hAFANYBc01ApgJ7wBm0+AFgJYQCUKAL7pMAW0bd4AExr0mrDtz6DkIkalCQYAITCFojAB75GOaTATw0mbHiKlyVVRkzQIxAA6MqAIk+E8J6+-ADcriKYAUHQALzQAIwATOEaOIwA7tB6zgB0ElKy-oHBYUA